# i found delete a node from xml object is extremely hard

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

the example of reference

```
var x1:XML = <x1>
                <a id = "52">AYY</a>
                <a>AYY 2 </a>
                <b>BEE</b>
                <c>CEE</c>
            </x1>;

trace(x1.toXMLString());
trace("___________");

delete x1.a.@id;

trace(x1.toXMLString());
trace("___________");

delete x1.b;

trace(x1.toXMLString());
trace("___________");

delete x1.a;

trace(x1.toXMLString());
```

output

```
<x1>
  <a id="52">AYY</a>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
___________
<x1>
  <a>AYY</a>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
___________
<x1>
  <a>AYY</a>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
___________
<x1>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
```

what if i only want to delete one element? or i want to delete the element which is  and has no child element?

i can only use delete x1.a. ridiculous! i spend hours and couldn't find a simple way .

```
var list:XMLList = x1.elements('a');
for each(var x:XML in list){
    if(....){
        //make something done
        //i want to delete this x from the xml object.while keep other node untouched.
    }
}
```

let me know the way you handle with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy... take a look:

```
var x1:XML = <x1>
                 <a id = "52">AYY</a>
                 <a>AYY 2 </a>
                 <b>BEE</b>
                 <c>CEE</c>
             </x1>;

trace(x1.toXMLString() + "\n");

var nodesToDelete:XMLList = x1.a;

trace(nodesToDelete.toXMLString() + "\n");

delete nodesToDelete[0];

trace(x1.toXMLString() + "\n");
```

Output:

```
<x1>
  <a id="52">AYY</a>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>

<a id="52">AYY</a>
<a>AYY 2</a>

<x1>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
```

And you can even do this:

```
delete x1.a[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the full E4X syntax to match nodes in the tree and delete those. For example this:

```
var x1:XML =
    <x1>
        <a id="52">AYY</a>
        <a>AYY 2</a>
        <b>BEE</b>
        <c>CEE</c>
    </x1>;

trace(x1.toXMLString());

delete x1.a.(hasOwnProperty('@id') && @id=='52')[0];

trace('---');
trace(x1.toXMLString());
```

Output:

```
<x1>
  <a id="52">AYY</a>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
---
<x1>
  <a>AYY 2</a>
  <b>BEE</b>
  <c>CEE</c>
</x1>
```